# Prepositional phrases but what about for super long phrases?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

"...consisting ***of direct and indirect interviews*, archival footage, re-enactments, and montage sequences**."

"...created ***by Leanne Allison* and Jeremy Mendes**."

"...forms ***including the Hildon and Sunsky Music Festivals* and the HGT Light Installation**."

If I am asked to highlight prepositional phrases, does it matter if it's super long? Like I understand that the bold words make up the entire prepositional phrase, but is it wrong to just highlight "of direct and indirect interviews" as the prepositional phrase when it's just followed by a bunch of other nouns? Or would it be wrong in that the WHOLE phrase has to be included?

Comment: It's not really a matter of English -- it's more a matter of typography and advertising design. If there's more **boldface** than normal type, something's wrong, because bold typefaces are meant to direct the attention, not to fade into the background.

Comment: @John I take it it's a school exercise.

Comment: Why not, is there a highlighter shortage? I know, it seems like too much, but that's probably the point of it.

Comment: *does it matter if it's super long?* No - not in the slightest.

Answer (score 1):

- What is the compound object of a preposition?

[[English Grammar  Parts of Speech  Prepositions_ M Amber; Socratic Q&A; italicisation mine](https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-compound-object-of-a-preposition#:%7E:text=It%20means%20that%20the%20object,library%2C%20and%20grocery%20store.%22)]

> The compound object of a preposition is when the object ([often a single] noun or
> pronoun) following a preposition is more than two objects.
>
> Explanation: This does not mean the object of the preposition is [necessarily] a
> plural word. It means that the object is two or more items. For
> instance:
>
> - Yesterday we went to the park, library, and grocery store.
>
> *The prepositional phrase is "to the park, library, and grocery store."*
>
> The preposition is "to." The compound object of the preposition is
> "park, library, and grocery store."